# Tangential and Normal directios in circular motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Let's consider the circular motion of an arm with the angular velocity vector directed in the z+ direction. If an object attached to the arm (so that it is completing the circular motion along with the arm) also has a constant speed in the x and z direction (so the magnitude of the radius of curvature is increasing and the object also is descending or ascending -while continuing the circular motion at the same rate-). Then we know that its speed at a certain moment is the translational speed relative to the center + the speed that comes from the circular motion.
Then, I claim that at a certain moment t the only component of the velocity in the tangential direction would be wxR (w being angular speed and R being the radius). It seems that this is not true and that a new "tangential direction" has to be considered due to the translational components of velocity, and thus, the radius of curvature when considering the normal acceleration formula is not the distance from the object to the center. How is this possible? Like, why do we have to consider a "tangential direction" that is not tangential and a "normal/centripetal direction" that is not normal?

Could somebody explain?

Comment: It seems you are talking about spiral motion outward from center. If so, then the position vector from the center of spiral is not at exact $\frac{\pi}{2}$ with the tangent. This will give a tangential and centripetal acceleration both.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "speed that comes from circular motion"?

Comment: @Proscionexium so then w x r is not the "tangential velocity" in this case, right?

Comment: @uberupense Actually $v=\omega r$ is always the tangential velocity. What is matter is whether it remains constant. If there is no tangential acceleration, it will remain constant otherwise it's value will change throughout the motion.